# How to write a simple if-statement for indexes 0 and 10, 1 and 11, 2 and 12 etc

Tags: php, loops, if-statement, math, laravel-blade

I need to write a condition for the index.
First condition do a function for indexes 0, 10, 20, 30
Second condition do a function for index 1, 11, 21, 31
Third condition do a function for index 2, 12, 22, 32
(..)

Actually I have look like:

```
@if ($loop->index == 0 || $loop->index == 10 || $loop->index == 20 || $loop->index == 30 || $loop->index == 40 || $loop->index == 50 || $loop->index == 60 || $loop->index == 70 || $loop->index == 80 || $loop->index == 90) 
   
     //do something
    
        ...
        
@elseif ($loop->index == 4 || $loop->index == 14 || $loop->index == 24 || $loop->index == 34 || $loop->index == 44 || $loop->index == 54 || $loop->index == 64 || $loop->index == 74 || $loop->index == 84 || $loop->index == 94) 

        ...

     // do something

@elseif ($loop->index == 9 || $loop->index == 19 || $loop->index == 29 || $loop->index == 39 || $loop->index == 49 || $loop->index == 59 || $loop->index == 69 || $loop->index == 79 || $loop->index == 89 || $loop->index == 99) 

    // do something

@endif
```

I know it doesn't look good, it works for me now, but I need advice because ***I have no idea how to write it a bit simpler.***

All the best,
Thanks.

Comment: `if ($loop->index % 10 == 0)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the modulo operator `%` to get the remainder when dividing.

```
@switch($loop->index % 10)
  @case(0)
    // 10,20,30 case...
    @break

  @case(1)
    // Second case...
    @break

  @default
    // otherwise
@endswitch
```

You can use switch, but you can use your @if/@elseif as well.

Answer (score 2):

For the first if use

`if ($loop->index % 10 == 0)`

for the second if use

`if (($loop->index-4) % 10 == 0)`

and for the last one use

`if (($loop->index-9) % 10 == 0)`

Answer (score 0):

you can save the modulus result to a variable first  `$mod = (($loop->index > 9 ) ? ($loop->index % 10) : $loop->index);`

```
@if ($mod == 0) 
     //do something
        
@elseif ($mod == 4) 

     // do something

@elseif ($mod == 9) 

    // do something

@endif
```